# Dependency caching in Python CI pipeline in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, pip, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, conda

I followed the [pip section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#pythonpip) on the Azure documentation on [pipeline caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops) to speed up my Azure DevOps CI pipeline (in particular the dependency installation step). However, the packages are still installed *every time* I execute the pipeline (which I ideally also want to cache). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Azure DevOps documentation is a bit lackluster here. Following the [pip section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#pythonpip) just leads to caching of the wheels, *not* the installation itself (which you can also cache to further improve the pipeline execution time). To enable this, you need to work with a virtual environment (such as [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) or a [conda environment](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/environments.html)) and cache the entire environment.

Below you can find a code example with `conda` on how to cache an entire installed environment:

```yaml
variables:
  CONDA_ENV_NAME: "unit_test"

  # set $(CONDA) environment variable to your conda path (pre-populated on 'ubuntu-latest' VMs)
  CONDA_ENV_DIR: $(CONDA)/envs/$(CONDA_ENV_NAME)

steps:
- script: echo "##vso[task.prependpath]$CONDA/bin"
  displayName: Add conda to PATH

- task: Cache@2
  displayName: Use cached Anaconda environment
  inputs:
    key: 'conda | "$(Agent.OS)" | requirements.txt'
    path: $(CONDA_ENV_DIR)
    cacheHitVar: CONDA_CACHE_RESTORED

- bash: conda create --yes --quiet --name $(CONDA_ENV_NAME)
  displayName: Create Anaconda environment
  condition: eq(variables.CONDA_CACHE_RESTORED, 'false')

- bash: |
    source activate $(CONDA_ENV_NAME)
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: Install dependencies
  condition: eq(variables.CONDA_CACHE_RESTORED, 'false')

# Optional step here: Install your package (do not cache this step)
- bash: |
    source activate $(CONDA_ENV_NAME)
    pip install --no-deps .
    pytest .
  displayName: Install package and execute unit tests
```

Comment: I also wrote a blog article on the topic for anyone wanting a bit more of an in-depth perspective: https://medium.com/@andre.gensler/guide-how-to-speed-up-your-python-continuous-integration-pipeline-in-azure-devops-using-dependency-916d9cd792a0